# Field explode in Typo3 TCA Array possible?

Tags: arrays, typo3

Is it possible somehow to use some kind of explode in TCA?

What I have is a DB field looking like:

```
10;20;30;40-80
```

Now it would be nice to have some kind of explode to use a new input field or checkboxes or whatever for each string between ";" :

```
        'number10' => array(        
                    'exclude' => 0,     
                    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mq_programm/locallang_db.xml:tx_mqprogramm_form.number',        
                    'config' => array(
                        'type' => 'input',
                        'size' => '30',
                    )
                ),
        'number20' => array(        
                    'exclude' => 0,     
                    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mq_programm/locallang_db.xml:tx_mqprogramm_form.number',        
                    'config' => array(
                        'type' => 'input',
                        'size' => '30',
                    )
                ),
        'number30' => array(        
                    'exclude' => 0,     
                    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mq_programm/locallang_db.xml:tx_mqprogramm_form.number',        
                    'config' => array(
                        'type' => 'input',
                        'size' => '30',
                    )
                ),
        'number40-80' => array(     
                    'exclude' => 0,     
                    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mq_programm/locallang_db.xml:tx_mqprogramm_form.number',        
                    'config' => array(
                        'type' => 'input',
                        'size' => '30',
                    )
                ),
```

and so on... Ofcourse I also need them in the showitem array:

```
'types' => array(
    '0' => array('showitem' => 'hidden;;1-1-1, number10, number20, number30, number40-80')
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tca.php is a normal PHP file and therefore you can use PHP in there. I don't know where and how you get your DB value from, but if you have it, use it:

```
$fieldIdentifiers = '10;20;30;40-80';
$fieldIdentifierArray = explode(';', $fieldIdentifiers);

$dynamicFields = array();
foreach ($fieldIdentifierArray as $fieldIdentifier) {
  $dynamicFields['number' . $fieldIdentifier] = array(
    'exclude' => 0,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mq_programm/locallang_db.xml:tx_mqprogramm_form.number' . $fieldIdentifier,
    'config' => array(
      'type' => 'input',
      'size' => '30',
    ),
  );
}
```

Then merge your dynamic fields with the existing fields

```
$TCA['tx_mqprogramm_form']['columns'] = array_merge($TCA['tx_mqprogramm_form']['columns'], $dynamicFields);
```

You can use a similar way for the showitem stuff.

Don't forget to find a way to create the database field since you cannot have a dynamic ext_tables.sql.

Comment: thanks for that. i try using something else now. its not viable to do that in a nice/dynamic and easy way.

Comment: I suggest to use FlexForms for that.